# Designing unified codebase to handle two separate XML Schemas

Tags: c++, xml, c++17, software-design, conditional-compilation

### Background

I have one XSD schema file that describes **hundreds** of individual messages in a messaging format used for communication between systems. We will call this XSD version 1.

I have another XSD version 2 that is a successor to version 1. It adds extra message types, changes the names of some previously defined messages from version 1, and it may add some data here and there. Basically the creator has no respect for backwards compatibility

I have a codebase that implements a lot of generic functionality using this messaging system from version 1. To do this I used a C++ code generator that generates code from the XSD. It works great and creates hundreds of objects I can reference in my code.

I did the same for version 2, copied the codebase and made edits to make it functional based on new messages and name changes. Again it works great and I am happy with it by itself.

## The Problem

The problem I have is maintaining two codebases that compile against the two versions of generated C++ code. A lot of the code is common code so it bothers me having two codebases but this was the least complex implementation in terms of time. Now that I have the time, I would like to better design this and keep just one codebase that will conditionally use functionality based on the Schema version that is configured upon compilation or runtime (im open to whatever would make this more maintainable).

I am having trouble figuring out how I could make sure I only have to maintain one codebase. I thought about using #ifdef's to conditionally compile but it seems like it will not be very maintainable in the long term based on how many tiny little differences might exist in many many places.

I read some other SO questions and [one mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403557/alternative-to-conditional-compilation-in-c-using-multiple-cpp-files) one header (common interface) and multiple cpp file solution to separate the functionality. This sounds great but its difficult because extra data can come or go in the future schemas. So a truly common interface is difficult especially when data is removed and added in version 2.

Generated code for hundreds of messages makes any significant edits to the generated code difficult to make reliably. I thought about separating them by adding a namespace to the two versions of the generated code, but I still have the problem of not being able to write one version of my common C++ code. It would need to reference version1::Message1 and version2::Message1 which could be significantly different.

#ifdef's seem great for OS related conditional compilation. But my situation feels different and I am wondering if anyone has any ideas (maybe even a design pattern) that sounds like it could handle this sort of problem. Anyone with experience dealing with multiple versions of "similar" XSD schemas would be great to hear from.

If the answer is "Dont do this" I understand, I was just hoping someone might have a good design idea that could spur a solution with some extra thought on my end.

### "Schema" Example

Here is a brief example that describes in pseudocode how the XML messages will look and how they differ from Version 1 to Version 2.

Version 1

```
Message1
    MessageHeader
        timestamp
    MetaData
        data
    MessageData
        data0
        data1
        data2

Message2
    MessageHeader
        timestamp
    MetaData
        data
    MessageData
        data3
        data4
```

Version 2 (Removes metadata found in each message inversion 1, adds a new message, changes the name of a Message2)

```
Message1
    MessageHeader
        timestamp
    MessageData
        data0
        data1
        data2

RenamedMessage2
    MessageHeader
        timestamp
    MessageData
        data3
        data4
        newData5

NewMessage3
    MessageHeader
        timestamp
    MessageData
        data6
        data7
```

### C++

```
ClassThatOperatesOnMessage2.cpp
ClassThatOperatesOnMessage1.cpp
CommonFramework.cpp
```

Example Future C++ code

```
ClassThatOperatesOnMessage3.cpp
```

Comment: Classic problem, I'm afraid, seen it all too often. Data-binding as a way of handling XML seems so appealing, until the schema changes and you're screwed. Can't offer any advice other than "don't start from here".

Comment: @MichaelKay I agree mostly. Handling the change in schema is no big deal, i regenerate the C++ and its handled fine. The problem is interoperability or backwards compatibility... Unfortunately I do not control the XSD so those sort of things are out of my hands. I feel like if protobuf was used, this would be much less of a problem. How would you approach handling XML like this other than auto code generation? I am definitely open to other approaches. I just wish XML was not the chosen format :(

Comment: I don't think one can offer professional advice on application architecture in an exchange like this, with no detailed knowledge of the project backgrounds and constraints, but in the past I have helped clients move away from data binding and adopt technologies like XSLT and XQuery, often resulting in a vast reduction in application complexity.

Comment: I appreciate the names of those technologies. I looked into them quickly and did not see how they would apply to my use-case unfortunately. The real conundrum here is that the schema is not well kept for backwards compatibility. In the end, Im not sure any tools can get around irresponsible schema changes. Separate code bases might be annoying but it might just be the only real option unless someone else comments with an interesting idea.

Comment: XSLT and XQuery are designed with a type system designed to accommodate the flexibility typically found in XML; you can use as much or as little schema information as you wish (most people use them as dynamically-typed languages). With XSLT in particular, you can usually accommodate schema changes by adding a couple of template rules, and existing code will continue to function. It's a different mind-set, where you assume things are going to change, whereas data binding assumes things are going to stay the same.

Comment: Interesting, so if I dont own the schema, its owned by someone else. When they change it, I could have my own XSLT document that helps me manage the changes they have made to the schema? Basically acting as some kind of intermediary to help manage changes? So say Schema Version 1 vs Schema Version 2 in my example above. If I could convert all Version 1 XML to the Version 2 equivalent, I could bind to Version 2 only. Thats if I am understanding things correctly anyways. This sounds very interesting and I may need to look into that deeper.

Comment: I appreciate the time you have put into replying to my post here by the way. I dont think I could have ran into someone better suited to at least give me a direction. Gotta love stack. 
For now the codebases will be separate. But I will definitely have a look at XSLT further to see if it could help me maintain a clean data bind.

Comment: One approach given where you're starting from would be to continue to use data binding supporting a single schema, and to use XSLT to convert incoming documents to the schema used by the data binding application.